# Tokbox Publisher become the subscriber at web

Tags: opentok, tokbox

1 publisher is publishing the stream from the Android device and the other 3 subscribers are join them from the Web.
Now at the web portion, my actual publisher has changed and the local host become the publisher and all other become the subscriber.

How to resolve it?

[image]
[image]

my code

```
function initializeSession(token,sessionId) 
{
     var session = OT.initSession(apiKey, sessionId);
     session.on('streamCreated', function streamCreated(event) 
     {
        var subscriberOptions = {
        insertMode: 'append',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'

    };
    console.log("New stream in the session: " + event.stream.streamId);
    session.subscribe(event.stream, 'publisher', subscriberOptions, handleError);
  });

  var publisherOptions = {
    insertMode: 'append'
  };
  var publisher = OT.initPublisher('subscriber', publisherOptions, handleError);

  session.connect(token, function(error) {
    if (error) {
      handleError(error);
    } else {
      session.publish(publisher, handleError);
    }
  });
}
```